# Let $f : (-1; 1) \to \Bbb R$. Assume that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) /|x| = 1$. Then $f$ is non differentiable at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f : (-1; 1) \to \Bbb R$. Assume that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) /|x| = 1$. Then $f$ is non differentiable at $x = 0$. I think the title is correct because we proved in class that $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but can I say that the statement is true because of that? (due to arithmetic of limits).

Comment: What about $f (x)=\sin (x) $?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar think about it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is continuous at $0$, because otherwise, $f$ is not differentiable anyway. Then, $f(0) = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {f(x)} {|x|} |x| = 1 \cdot 0 = 0$.

The right derivative is $1$, since the right derivative is $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {f(h) - f(0)} h = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {f(h)} {|h|} = 1$.

The left derivative is $-1$, since the left derivative is $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac {f(h) - f(0)} h = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac {f(h)} {-|h|} = -1$.

Since the left and right derivatives do not agree at $0$, $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.